# How to retrieve the key from the shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a doubt, I don't know how to retrieve the key from the shared preference?

Answer (score 4):

Use [getAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29) and iterate over the map to get the keys.

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = sharedPrefs.getAll();

for(Map.Entry entry : prefs.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. This solution really very help full for me.